# How do I get the individual digits of a number?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

i want to split up a raw_input into many integers like this

```
TheString = raw_input

>>>12345678
```

and then spit up TheString to integers

```
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
d3 = 3
d4 = 4
d5 = 5
d6 = 6
d7 = 7
d8 = 8
```

I tried to find it but it did not work what the others suggested.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use different variable names for each digit. You can convert the string to a list of integers and index the list to get each digit.

```
>>> s = "314159" # or s = raw_input()
>>> d = map(int, s)
>>> d[0]
3
>>> d[1]
1
```